# Echo a command back to to bash shell prompt?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to implement a simple command line util that will allow users to select from a set of commands and then echo those commands strings back to the shell.  I don't want the shell to execute said commands, but I want the commands to simply echo out to the prompt, so the user can verify them or change them before pressing return button.

No idea where to start.  Of course echoing the command to STDOUT is pretty easy with a log command, or println kind of thing, but that would be the stdout of current process, Ideally, I would like the stdout of that process to be the stdin of the shell, but only into the prompt line, not a pipe into a new shell or a command execution.  Is this possible?

e.g.

```sh
$ help # user asks for help
1. you can do this
2. you can do that
? 1 # user chooses 1, help echoes back a string to the parent shell $$

$ this-command --flags # simply ends up on prompt line, but doesn't exec
```

Is this possible without a hook in the terminal ui or tty?

Comment: Why do you want to use `bash` for that purpose? I would suggest using something better. It would be simpler to write an utility using [GNU readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) in whatever Linux programming language you are familiar with (e.g. in [guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), [lua](http://lua.org/) etc...)

Comment: `zsh` has the feature you want: `print -z foo` puts `foo` in the input buffer.

Comment: bash, is not a requirement per se, just happens to be what I like.  in fact I would like this to be agnostic to shell flavor, so I can't really use a shell specific feature.  GNU Readline might provide the abstraction I need.

Comment: In Bash, you can use `read -e -i "$command"` to get a user prompt that's pre-populated with `$command`; after the user has edited it, it'll live in `$REPLY` and you can do what you want with it, e.g., run it as a command. (Or `read -e -i "$command" input` to read into `$input` instead of `$REPLY`.)

Comment: It sounds to me like your talking about the [Bash select command](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_06.html) . Also available in ksh* and I would assume zsh. Don't know about the others. The example shows `select n in *; do...` but you can put any list you like in place of the `*`.  Good luck.

Comment: yes, `print -z foo` in zsh does exactly what I want, not sure if read -e does the same thing bash.

Comment: See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213821/271136).